# what do we need the Parent parameter in QMainWindow() for?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm relatively new to Python and am currently working on the QtWidget. In my online course we created our own class that inherits from QtWidgets.QMainWindow. When creating the constructor, we created a parameter called Parent, what do we need it for? I've also read the official documentation, but I can't make any sense of it.

This is the code:

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets
from ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)



    def on_button_click(self):
        self.weight = self.ui.weight.value()
        self.height = self.ui.height.value()

        if self.weight and self.height != 0:
            self.rechnung = (self.weight) / (self.height ** 2)
            self.ui.result.setText(f"Dein BMI hat einen Wert von {round(self.rechnung, 2)}")

        else:
            self.ui.result.setText("Deine eingaben dürfen keine 0 enthalten")



window = MainWindow()

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

we pass this parameter to the QtWidgets.QMainWindow() class, but for what?

Comment: - Your `MainWindow` class of type `QtWidgets.QMainWindow`, it MAY receive an argument at the moment when it is instantiated.
.
- Since the `parent` argument was set to `None`,
gives the possibility to instantiate your MainWindow class WITH or WITHOUT this argument.
.
- In this example this argument is not being used. But I believe that in the next classes of your course this argument will be further explored.

Comment: Also, see the documentation about [QObject and object trees](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html).